# Algebra: Is $f(x) = \frac x x$ the same as $f(x) = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is basically: can we simplify $f(x) = \frac x x$ to $f(x) = 1$ without considering $f(0)$?

Second, if they are not the same thing how can we simplify equations like $x + 2xy = 5x$ to $1 + 2y = 5$ by dividing both sides by $x$ if the value of $x$ could be $0$. In other words: are unknowns in algebraic equations different from function variables?

And finally, the only solution to $x = 2x$ must be $0$ otherwise, $1 = 2$ so we can't divide both sides by $0$ in this case. Is this related to the proof in those YouTube videos titled "Stump your math teacher. Proof of $1=2$"?

Comment: You cannot divide by $x$ if the value of $x$ could be zero. What you CAN do is bring the $5x$ term to the left hand side and factor an $x$ upfront. Indeed, the equation $x=2x$ yields zero and zero only

Comment: Well if I bring the $5x$ term to the left it becomes $-4x + 2xy = 0$, factoring an x yields: $x(-4 + 2y) = 0$ which again would require that we divide by $x$.

Comment: Why would you have to divide by $x$, one can see that a valid solution is $x=0$ at this stage or $-4+y=0$ as one of the factors must equal $0$ for the expression to be equal to $0$?

Comment: No, you would not divide. You would use the zero product property. If $AB=0$ then $A=0$ or $B=0$, and so you would get $x=0$ or $-4+y=0$. The zero product property for solving equations must be somewhere in your precalculus book

Comment: What if I'm solving for $y$ given that both $x$ and $y$ are variables?

Comment: We need to know more context, e.g. if $f$ denotes a *polynomial* then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases we cannot divide by $x$ if there is a possibility that $x=0$. The equations must be solved by factorisation and considering that $x=0$ could be a valid solution. For the function $f(x)=\frac{x}x$, this is equal to $1$ only where $x\ne0$ so for example we can say that
$$f(x)=\frac{x}x=1\text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{R^+}$$
but
$$f(x)=\frac{x}x\ne1\text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Your last equation looks to me like it's saying, "For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x/x$ is a number other than $1$." Maybe you should write something like "it's not the case that $f(x) = x/x = 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$"?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is defined as $f(x)={x\over x}$ then $f$ is undefined at $x=0.$  It would be correct to say $f(x)=1,\ x\neq0.$  As for simplifying the equation, there are two cases, either $x=0$ and any value of $y$ gives a solution, or $x\neq0$ and $y$ satisfies $1+2y=5.$

Whenever you want to divide by some algebraic expression, you must either check that it can't be $0$, or consider the case where it does evaluate to $0$ separately. There are no circumstances under which you can divide by $0.$

I don't know the video, but lots of false proofs are based on dividing by $0$.  There are no circumstances in which you can divide by $0.$

Answer (score 1):

The issue of $\frac{x}{x}$ and $1$ being differnt functions because they have different domains has been adequately addressed in other answers.

There are basically two ways to attack $x+2xy=5x$.  The first is the method you have been taught: bring everything to one side of the equal sign and factor:
\begin{align*}
x + 2 x y - 5 x &= 0  \\
2 x y - 4 x &= 0  \\
2x( y - 2) &= 0
\end{align*}
For the product of two numbers to be zero, one or both are zero, so either $x=0$ or $y = 2$ (or both).

Alternatively, one may track the possibility that you have inadvertently divided by zero in parallel:
\begin{align*}
x + 2 x y &= 5 x  \\
1 + 2 y &= 5 &\text{ or } x &= 0  \\
y &= 2 &\text{ or } x &= 0
\end{align*}
You get the same result either way since the logical/mathematical usage of the word "or" means "either or both".

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider two cases. If $x \ne 0$, then $\dfrac 1x$ exists and you can divide both sides by $x$, which is equivalent to multiplying both sides by $\dfrac 1x$.

\begin{align}
   x + 2xy &= 5x \\
   \dfrac{x + 2xy}{x} &= \dfrac{5x}{x} \\
   1+2y &= 5 \\
   y &= 2
\end{align}

If $x=0$, then you note that $x+2xy = 5x = 0$. Regardless of the value of $y$. 
Your solution would therefore be

$$ y = \begin{cases}
   2 & \text{If $x \ne 0$} \\
   \text{Any real number} & \text{If $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$